# How to create order programmatically with customer email in magento 1.9

Tags: php, programmatically, magento1.9.2.3, place-order, customer-emails

I  want to place order with customer email id in magento 1.9
For this i need a script means i want to do it programmatically in php 
Please help asap

Comment: Customer is already registered?

Comment: yes customer is already registered but  we can add this place order functionality for guest user also.

Comment: Not working with bundle product. can you change according to code bundle & Simple product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a php file in your Magento root directory named create_order.php(you can change the file name according to your requirement)

Add the below code to your create_order.php

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite();

//Create sales quote object
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getStoreId());

//Customer information
$customerEmail = "example@example.com";
$customerFirstname = "Joe"; 
$customerLastname = "Doe";

$billingAddress = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $customerFirstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $customerLastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => 'Your Street Address 1', // required
        '1' => 'Your Street Address 1' // optional
    ),
    'city' => 'Your City',
    'country_id' => 'US', // country code
    'region' => 'Alaska',
    'region_id' => '2',
    'postcode' => '45263',
    'telephone' => '999-888-0000',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

$shippingAddress = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $customerFirstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $customerLastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => 'Your Street Address 1', // required
        '1' => 'Your Street Address 1' // optional
    ),
    'city' => 'Your City',
    'country_id' => 'US', // country code
    'region' => 'Alaska',
    'region_id' => '2',
    'postcode' => '45263',
    'telephone' => '999-888-0000',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

//Check whether the customer already registered or not
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($website->getId())->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

if (!$customer->getId()) {

    //Create the new customer account if not registered
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer'); 
    $customer->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
             ->setStore($store)
             ->setFirstname($customerFirstname)
             ->setLastname($customerLastname)
             ->setEmail($customerEmail);

    try {
        $password = $customer->generatePassword(); 
        $customer->setPassword($password);

        //Set the customer as confirmed
        $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
        $customer->save();

        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        //Set customer address
        $customerId = $customer->getId(); 
        $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address'); 
        $customAddress->setData($billingAddress)
                      ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                      ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                      ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        //Save customer address
        $customAddress->save();

        //Send new account email to customer
        $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);

        //Set password remainder email if the password is auto generated by magento
        $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    } 
}

//Assign the customer to quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

//Set currency for the quote
$quote->setCurrency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode());

$productIds = array(500 => 2, 501 => 4); //array('product_id' => 'qty')

//Add products to quote
foreach($productIds as $productId => $qty) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
}

//Add billing address to quote
$billingAddressData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddress);

//Add shipping address to quote
$shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress);

//Collect shipping rates on quote
$shippingAddressData->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();

//Set shipping method and payment method on the quote
$shippingAddressData->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //Shipping is flatrate for this example

//Set payment method for the quote
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo')); //Payment is check and money order for this example

try {
    //Collect totals & save quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    //Create order from quote
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

    echo 'Order Id: ' .$increment_id. ' has been successfully created.';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is working fine,But i want to place order.
I  mean to say this script is adding product to cart.

Comment: order is showing pending status in the back end

Comment: This script is adding product to cart after that it adding the customer details and creates quotes. After that it converting into order. If you want to change the order status programmatically I can share you the code

Comment: no sir its okay with status but 1 more modification if we want to add multiple products with different quantity ? pls help me on this

Comment: sku- quanity
sku-quantity 
like this i want to add multiple sku with different quantity for each

Comment: Please check this line: $productIds = array(500 => 2, 501 => 4); You can add more products and quantity on this array. This array contains 500, 501 as product id and 2,4 as quantity of those products. If you have skus and quantity then you will get the product ids by loading the product and then create this array according to your requirement.

Comment: @SukumarGorai How can we add the orders with order status as completed? How can we add orders in magento 2.3 programatically

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you post a question?